# Spring transaction not rolled back on Hibernate StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, optimistic-locking

I have a scenario as below

```
methodA(){

try{
  objB.methodB();
}
catch(Exception ex){
  log(exception caught);
}

@Transactional(value = "txManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackFor={Exception.class, StaleObjectStateException.class})
methodB(){
   methodC();
}

@Transactional(value = "txManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class,StaleObjectStateException.class})
methodC(){
  /*Some logic that throws HOLF/SOSE exception. Essentially calling merge on entity that has @Version enabled
}
```

My issue is, for a given flow i may have two request calling this method at same time. I expect methodC to throw exception for Optimistic locking failure and transaction to be rolled back.

My Expectation was:

Lets say i have two requests R1 and R2
R1 and R2 call methodA ->methodB (Starts a new transaction) ->methodC(transaction propogated) : both read same entity version, both make same changes and call merge -> methodC completes flow back to methodB -> methodB completes forcing transaction to commit-> transaction commit calls session.flush , gets run time exception for optimistic locking and is rolled back.

I do get the SOSE exception in method A , i can see it in my loggers but the transaction is committed and both the records are getting persisted.

Whats happening is as below:
R1 and R2 call methodA ->methodB (Starts a new transaction) ->methodC(transaction propogated) : both read same entity version, both make same changes and call merge -> methodC completes flow back to methodB -> methodB completes forcing transaction to commit-> transaction commits -> throws run time exception for optimistic locking DOESN'T roll back and exception is caught by methodA.

If i explicitly throw an exception in methodC, transaction does get rolled back.

I am not sure why its not rolling back the transaction when the Optimisitc lock failure exception is thrown.

Please advise

Comment: Are you getting the exception for both R1 and R2 requests or only for R2?

Comment: Its sporadic. Which ever updates entity first, for second one i get exception. But the entry is still committed

Comment: Well if thirst update completes without error then it will commit the change?

Comment: both transactions are independent. Lets say my existing record has version 1. When R1 and R2 comes both read version 1. R1 updates record and now version is 2. When R2 tries to update , it has version 1 but db has version 2 so i will get stale object exception and the record should not be persisted.
However, i see 3 records now in DB. One from R1 and one from R2 and the old record thats been updated.

As per optimistic locking , i was expecting the transaction for R2 to rollback.
Am i missing something?

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe you can post sample code for `methodC` and we could help you further.

Comment: The logic is simple. Lets say my entity is TableA with a flag that can be set 'Y' or 'N'. method C will have logic as below

    TableA clone=originalObj;

    originalObj.setFlag('N');

    merge(originalObj);

    merge(cloneObj);

Comment: What is your spring configuration? More specifically, what is the `<aop>` configuration? Is your component proxied through interface or via CGLib?

Comment: not using aop. spring config is as below
`<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <qualifier value="txManager"/>
    </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />`

Comment: As i said, i do get an exception. But it's not rolling the transaction back

Comment: I was just trying something. It seems if i explicitly call session.flush() in methodC it throws a runtime exception and the transaction rolls back. I am guessing the issue could be with transaction propogation, as in that case it calls flush after methodB completes and somehow it commits nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. So i seems to have it working. Turns out the issue is with JTA provider. I was deploying the code on Tomee  this will ensure Spring picks the provider from tomcat lib and it was using Gerenimo which seems to be not handling roll back.
I pushed the same code on weblogic and used  org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform as JTA provider, this seems to be working as expected. 
Will post if i get the reason why Gerenimo was not working or if there is something i am missing on it.